# Wrapping a UITableViewController in NSProxy

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a subclass of `NSProxy` designed to forward messages to either an object instance or to Lua functions if they are defined for the selector. This works in most cases. `UITableViewController`, however, is a different case altogether. When I set up my proxy object with an instance of `UITableViewController` (or a stub subclass) it doesn't seem to ever receive any of the `UITableViewDelegate` or `UITableViewDatasource` messages that I expect it to.

I have the necessary methods implemented up in Lua, and they respond correctly when called manually, but they never seem to be called when I add the proxy `UIViewController` view to the hierarchy. What might I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting tripped up by the way that some UIKit classes handle their delegate connection.  They keep a set of flags internally indicating what messages the delegate can respond to.  When you set the delegate or datasource outlet, the TableView will send several `-respondsToSelector:` messages to the object in question, and remember which ones returned `TRUE`.